# How to assign an item/var as an updated dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code like this that assigns an item as dict that is an updated different dict:

```
lang1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
langs = {'lang1'：lang1,'lang2':lang1.update({3:'g'})}
print(langs['lang2'])
```

When I do that I got the output 'None'. Is there anyway to do this so if I `print(langs[lang2][3])` it gets 'g'

Comment: The line `lang1.update({3:'g'})` returns `None`, therefor `langs['lang2']` will return `None`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict.update` does not return anything, it modifies the existing dict.
if you are using python 3.9 and up you can do

```
lang1 | {3:'g'}
```

if you are not then you can do:

```
{**lang1, 3:'g'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
lang1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
lang2 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
lang2.update({3:'g'})
langs = {'lang1':lang1, 'lang2':lang2}
print(langs['lang2'])
```

Recommend you to check out `dict.update` and various other methods:

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp